# How to create reset filter in dash board in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

Please suggest me how to create

if 
I click reset filter button automatically clear the filter and display as original filter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The following Tableau Knowledgebase article will guide you through the process of creating a filter reset button in Tableau Desktop:

http://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/creating-a-button-to-clear-all-filters-in-a-dashboard